# Displaying a <div> at a particular index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm developing a comment system using jquery. Actually i'm stuck at the portion of displaying the  portion, which displays the form at particular index. Suppose that i've 5 links. If i click on the 4th link, the form should be displayed at the 4th link position. But whenever i click on any of the link position, the form is getting displayed at the first link position. This should display as we see in a commenting system. I don't know if have to get some row position or something like that. A sample code from the jsfiddle has been posted below. If i have 3 links, whenever i click on any link, the form will be displayed at first link. I would like to fix this issue. Please help. Thank You

Here's the jsfiddle link 
"http://jsfiddle.net/5UMe9/1/"

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.commentSystem = function() {
        //var settings = $.extend({index:ind});
        //if(settings.index)
        $(this).show();        
    }
}(jQuery));



$(document).ready( function() {                       
    hideForm();
    createLink();
    onLinkClick();
});
```

Comment: based on your code...the current purpose of the `commentSystem` function is to simply show your form where it sits in the DOM. You haven't added anything to actually move the form into the correct position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to accomplish your goal is to append the `form` to the `div` element that has the currently clicked link. In that case, you could pass in the clicked element, and append your form inside the `commentSystem` method.

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZDgx6/1/

JS:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.commentSystem = function(link) {
        $(this).insertAfter(link).show();   
    }
}(jQuery));
.
.
.
$(".link").click(function(e){
    $(".Form").commentSystem(e.currentTarget);
});
```

Comment: I'm getting a weird behavior in my code. I'm not able to input anything in all the textboxes. Please have a look at the js fiddle, you provided. Thank You

Comment: I think we could use $(this).insertAfter(link).show(), so that we can input data to the text boxes

Comment: Yes, the reason `.insertAfter()` works and `.appendTo` does not is specific to your code. You have a `click` event bound to all DOM elements containing the `link` class. In this case, it's a `div` element surrounding the actual 'reply' link. Therefore, when you try to click into the input field to enter some text, it triggers the `.commentSystem` method and moves your form again. In any event, `.appendTo` could work, but you would need to adjust your HTML markup a bit. Hope that helps explain the issue.